# LEFT OUTER JOIN not always matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I'm starting with a SQL query with a couple of joins and I'm getting the exact data I expect.  This is what the current query is.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourCd, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
FROM Lab_Space l
JOIN Worker w ON l.Contact_WWID = w.WWID AND w.Employee_Status_Code = 'A'
JOIN Org_Hierarchy o ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm IS NOT NULL AND w.Org_Hierarchy_Unit_Cd = o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd
ORDER BY o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
```

This ends up with a row like

> 1234 | Finance | IT

Now I've created a new table, where I'm tracking whether or not I want to include the organization in my output.  That table just has two columns, an org ID and a bit field.  So I thought I could `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, since the second table won't have data on *all* orgs, so I expanded the query to this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourCd, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, v.Include
FROM Lab_Space l
JOIN Worker w ON l.Contact_WWID = w.WWID AND w.Employee_Status_Code = 'A'
JOIN Org_Hierarchy o ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm IS NOT NULL AND w.Org_Hierarchy_Unit_Cd = o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd
LEFT OUTER JOIN Validation_Email_Org_Unit_Inclusion v ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd = v.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd
ORDER BY o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
```

The problem I have is now I end up with rows like so:

> 1234 | Finance | IT | NULL
>   1234 | Finance | IT | 1

Since the `Validation_Email_Org_Unit_Inclusion` table includes a `1` for the 1234 org, I would expect to just get a single row with a value of 1, not include the row with NULL.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `Validation_Email_Org_Unit_Inclusion` would appear to have two row, one with  `Include` as `NULL` and one with `Include` as `1`.

Comment: There are two rows total in the table right now.  One with org 1234 and a value of 1, and another with org 5678 and a value of 0.

Comment: Do you only want to output rows, where a corresponding row with `Validation_Email_Org_Unit_Inclusion = 1` exists? Or also a row where no entry in your include or not table exists?

Comment: I want to see all the rows from the initial query, and now add another column that shows `NULL` if `Validation_Email_Org_Unit_Inclusion` does not contain a value for the org id, or the value of the bit field if the org ID is there.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You output `OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourCd` but currently join on `OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd`. Join on the same column you output to get the corresponding value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourCd, ...
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN Validation_Email_Org_Unit_Inclusion v ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourCd = v.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd
...
```